# Set event listener based on text param from js function

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a function that will allow me to set a buttons text and onclick property

Both are set as text params

Here is the function:

```
function assignButton(n,text,onclick){
  var btn = document.getElementById("button" + n)
  btn.innerHTML = text
  btn.onclick = function(){onclick}
}
```

here is what I call

```
assignButton(13,"Exit Program","alert('Goodbye')")
```

The button text is properly assigned but the text that I want to execute is not assigned in the onclick property.  It works if I directly type in some code in the function but not when I pass it through as text...

Any ideas on what I could do to get this concept working?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Don't pass a string, pass a function - then `btn.onclick = onclick`

Comment: How do I pass a function?

Comment: `, () => alert('Goodbye')`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, if you leave an answer I will accept and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function to the `assignButton` as the `onclick` parameter, and then you'll be able to use that to invoke the button's `onclick` setter.

```js
function assignButton(n,text,onclick){
  var btn = document.getElementById("button" + n)
  btn.textContent = text;
  btn.onclick = onclick;
}
assignButton(13,"Exit Program",() => alert('Goodbye'))
```

```html
<button id="button13">button</button>
```

I'd recommend using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` when inserting *text* - it's safer and faster.

IDs shouldn't really be dynamic either. You might consider using classes instead, and then select the `n`th class.